# Does Cassandra 2.1 insert performance depends on affected columns?

Tags: java, performance, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Environment: Cassandra 2.1, DataStax Driver 2.1.9, single node cluster with DSE 4.8

I created a table:

```
create table calc_data_test2(
    data_set_id uuid,svod_type text,section text,index_code text,value_type text,data_hash text,c1 text,c2 text,c3 text,c4 text,c5 text,c6 text,c7 text,c8 text,c9 text,c10 text,c11 text,c12 text,c13 text,c14 text,c15 text,c16 text,c17 text,c18 text,c19 text,c20 text,c21 text,c22 text,c23 text,c24 text,c25 text,c26 text,c27 text,c28 text,c29 text,c30 text,c31 text,c32 text,c33 text,c34 text,c35 text,c36 text,c37 text,c38 text,c39 text,c40 text,c41 text,c42 text,c43 text,c44 text,c45 text,c46 text,c47 text,c48 text,c49 text,c50 text,c51 text,c52 text,c53 text,c54 text,c55 text,c56 text,c57 text,c58 text,c59 text,c60 text,c61 text,c62 text,c63 text,c64 text,c65 text,c66 text,c67 text,c68 text,c69 text,c70 text,c71 text,c72 text,c73 text,c74 text,c75 text,c76 text,c77 text,c78 text,c79 text,c80 text,c81 text,c82 text,c83 text,c84 text,c85 text,c86 text,c87 text,c88 text,c89 text,c90 text,c91 text,c92 text,c93 text,c94 text,c95 text,c96 text,c97 text,c98 text,c99 text,c100 text,se1 text,se2 text,data_value double,
    primary key ((data_set_id))
);
```

Then I made a few experiments with async inserts into the table. There were 1000000 inserts in the same table with 50 parallel request for each case. The difference in the count of affected columns. Here is the results:

- 85 columns - 143860 ms
- 65 columns - 108564 ms
- 45 columns - 78213 ms
- 25 columns - 68447 ms
- 5 columns - 49812 ms

The details below.

---

Insert of 85 columns:

```
>java -jar store-utils-cli.jar -pt "insert into csod.calc_data_test2(data_set_id, svod_type,section,index_code,value_type,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40,c41,c42,c43,c44,c45,c46,c47,c48,c49,c50,c51,c52,c53,c54,c55,c56,c57,c58,c59,c60,c61,c62,c63,c64,c65,c66,c67,c68,c69,c70,c71,c72,c73,c74,c75,c76,c77,c78,c79,c80) VALUES(now(), '58','9281','7611','367','7371','8353','4269','134','5884','6794','3147','7639','7798','7890','8547','4212','8630','5962','8686','4482','372','7218','6070','5525','1381','9816','5721','3632','5364','3980','6635','9641','518','6394','2560','1202','5595','7466','1507','7783','9586','6724','9169','9673','7867','8509','6889','3540','5994','4290','1925','8924','4704','4987','803','4291','4987','1111','4934','9885','6441','8212','9349','6852','6628','42','6713','3696','3316','8122','3288','3845','6063','5430','2052','5121','3343','6362','8724','2184','1380','5828','3723','8185');" 1000000 --cassandra.connection.requests.max.local=50
22:56:40,398  INFO ru.croc.rosstat.csod.store.cassandra.connection.CassandraCluster:-1 - Connection to CassandraSettings$Connection(nodes:[csodx01.lab.croc.ru], port:9042, keyspace:csod, requests:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests(fetchSize:1000, batchSize:2000, consistencyLevel:LOCAL_QUORUM, max:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max(local:50, remote:20, retry:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max$Retry(enabled:true, read:10, write:10, unavailable:5)))) established

Entering: Overall process
Entering: Prebuilding of statements
Leaving [1086 ms]: Prebuilding of statements
Entering: Executing statements async
Leaving [143860 ms][6951.202558042542 ops/s]: Executing statements async
Leaving [144954 ms]: Overall process
```

Insert of 65 columns:

```
>java -jar store-utils-cli.jar -pt "insert into csod.calc_data_test2(data_set_id, svod_type,section,index_code,value_type,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40,c41,c42,c43,c44,c45,c46,c47,c48,c49,c50,c51,c52,c53,c54,c55,c56,c57,c58,c59,c60) VALUES(now(), '58','9281','7611','367','7371','8353','4269','134','5884','6794','3147','7639','7798','7890','8547','4212','8630','5962','8686','4482','372','7218','6070','5525','1381','9816','5721','3632','5364','3980','6635','9641','518','6394','2560','1202','5595','7466','1507','7783','9586','6724','9169','9673','7867','8509','6889','3540','5994','4290','1925','8924','4704','4987','803','4291','4987','1111','4934','9885','6441','8212','9349','6852');" 1000000 --cassandra.connection.requests.max.local=50
00:28:27,393  INFO ru.croc.rosstat.csod.store.cassandra.connection.CassandraCluster:-1 - Connection to CassandraSettings$Connection(nodes:[csodx01.lab.croc.ru], port:9042, keyspace:csod, requests:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests(fetchSize:1000, batchSize:2000, consistencyLevel:LOCAL_QUORUM, max:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max(local:50, remote:20, retry:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max$Retry(enabled:true, read:10, write:10, unavailable:5)))) established

Entering: Overall process
Entering: Prebuilding of statements
Leaving [847 ms]: Prebuilding of statements
Entering: Executing statements async
Leaving [108564 ms][9211.15655281677 ops/s]: Executing statements async
Leaving [109413 ms]: Overall process
```

Insert of 45 columns:

```
>java -jar store-utils-cli.jar -pt "insert into csod.calc_data_test2(data_set_id, svod_type,section,index_code,value_type,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40) VALUES(now(), '58','9281','7611','367','7371','8353','4269','134','5884','6794','3147','7639','7798','7890','8547','4212','8630','5962','8686','4482','372','7218','6070','5525','1381','9816','5721','3632','5364','3980','6635','9641','518','6394','2560','1202','5595','7466','1507','7783','9586','6724','9169','9673');" 1000000 --cassandra.connection.requests.max.local=50
00:33:19,972  INFO ru.croc.rosstat.csod.store.cassandra.connection.CassandraCluster:-1 - Connection to CassandraSettings$Connection(nodes:[csodx01.lab.croc.ru], port:9042, keyspace:csod, requests:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests(fetchSize:1000, batchSize:2000, consistencyLevel:LOCAL_QUORUM, max:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max(local:50, remote:20, retry:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max$Retry(enabled:true, read:10, write:10, unavailable:5)))) established

Entering: Overall process
Entering: Prebuilding of statements
Leaving [845 ms]: Prebuilding of statements
Entering: Executing statements async
Leaving [78213 ms][12785.598302072545 ops/s]: Executing statements async
Leaving [79060 ms]: Overall process
```

Insert of 25 columns:

```
>java -jar store-utils-cli-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -pt "insert into csod.calc_data_test2(data_set_id, svod_type,section,index_code,value_type,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20) VALUES(now(), '58','9281','7611','367','7371','8353','4269','134','5884','6794','3147','7639','7798','7890','8547','4212','8630','5962','8686','4482','372','7218','6070','5525');" 1000000 --cassandra.connection.requests.max.local=50
00:39:29,337  INFO ru.croc.rosstat.csod.store.cassandra.connection.CassandraCluster:-1 - Connection to CassandraSettings$Connection(nodes:[csodx01.lab.croc.ru], port:9042, keyspace:csod, requests:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests(fetchSize:1000, batchSize:2000, consistencyLevel:LOCAL_QUORUM, max:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max(local:50, remote:20, retry:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max$Retry(enabled:true, read:10, write:10, unavailable:5)))) established

Entering: Overall process
Entering: Prebuilding of statements
Leaving [885 ms]: Prebuilding of statements
Entering: Executing statements async
Leaving [68447 ms][14609.844112963314 ops/s]: Executing statements async
Leaving [69339 ms]: Overall process
```

And insert of 5 columns:

```
>java -jar store-utils-cli-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -pt "insert into csod.calc_data_test2(data_set_id, svod_type,section,index_code,value_type) VALUES(now(), '58','9281','7611','367');" 1000000 --cassandra.connection.requests.max.local=50
00:43:35,293  INFO ru.croc.rosstat.csod.store.cassandra.connection.CassandraCluster:-1 - Connection to CassandraSettings$Connection(nodes:[csodx01.lab.croc.ru], port:9042, keyspace:csod, requests:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests(fetchSize:1000, batchSize:2000, consistencyLevel:LOCAL_QUORUM, max:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max(local:50, remote:20, retry:CassandraSettings$Connection$Requests$Max$Retry(enabled:true, read:10, write:10, unavailable:5)))) established

Entering: Overall process
Entering: Prebuilding of statements
Leaving [968 ms]: Prebuilding of statements
Entering: Executing statements async
Leaving [49812 ms][20075.483819160043 ops/s]: Executing statements async
Leaving [50782 ms]: Overall process
```

Is it really true that number of affected columns in an insert has so big impact on the performance? I haven't find any info about such dependency yet. May be I'm doing something wrong?

All meaningfull code for the inserts is here:

```
override fun run(args: Array<String?>) {
    if (args.isEmpty() || args.size < 2){
        System.err.println("You should specify a query and a number of iterations: ${args.toList()}")
        return
    }

    val query: String? = args[0]
    val iterationCount: Long = args[1]!!.toLong()

    // get the session
    val session: Session = cassandraCluster.connection().driverSession
    // prepare the query
    val preparedQuery: PreparedStatement = session.prepare(query)

    MeasureTime("Overall process").use {
        // create bound statements 
        val statements = MeasureTime("Prebuild statements").use {
            (1..iterationCount).map { BoundStatement(preparedQuery) }
        }

        // execute async
        MeasureTime("Execute statements async", iterationCount).use {
            val phaser = Phaser(1)
            statements.map { statement ->
                phaser.register()
                session.executeAsync(statement).withCallback({
                    phaser.arriveAndDeregister()
                }, { err ->
                    System.err.println(err)
                    phaser.arriveAndDeregister()
                })
            }
            // block until all tasks are done
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance()
        }
    }
}

// extension method for convenience
private fun <T> ListenableFuture<T>.withCallback(onSuccessCallback: (T?) -> Unit, onFailureCallback: (Throwable?) -> Unit): ListenableFuture<T> {
    Futures.addCallback(this, object: FutureCallback<T> {
        override fun onSuccess(p0: T?) {
            onSuccessCallback(p0)
        }

        override fun onFailure(p0: Throwable?) {
            onFailureCallback(p0)
        }
    })
    return this
}

class MeasureTime(val message: String, val operationCount: Long? = null): Closeable {
    private val startTime: Long

    init {
        startTime = System.nanoTime()
        System.out.println("Entering: $message")
    }

    override fun close() {
        val endTime = System.nanoTime()
        val elapsed = (endTime - startTime)/1000000
        val opStats = if (operationCount != null) {
            val f = operationCount/elapsed.toDouble()*1000
            "[$f ops/s]"
        } else ""
        val message = "Leaving [$elapsed ms]$opStats: $message"
        System.out.println(message)
    }
}
```

I believe it's not a problem for Java-man to understand what's going on in the kotlin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're inserting more data in the second table than in the 1st one (c1 to c100 + couple of other cols) then it's normal that the insert is slower.

Now, even if you insert the same amount of data (in term of bytes count) in both tables, the insert in the 2nd table will still be a little bit slower because of:

1. the overhead of meta data. You have more columns so there are more objects to create in memory to store them
2. the CPU consumption to serialize a lot of columns instead of a few of them
3. and maybe I forget other parameters

Comment: Yes, you're right. So I've updated the question to measure only the dependency of the execution time on the number of columns.